# How to connect the origin with the model?

Tags: modeling, interface

[image]

The control gizmo is at the world origin but the model is far away as you can see. How do you get the two things back together and how is this even possible?

Comment: Hi :). The small orange dot is the *Origin Point*. Control gizmo always shows on the origin, not the geometry. You need to align the origin with your geometry :))

Comment: Hello and welcome! BSE is a question & answer site. Please give your questions a meaningful title and a brief explanation of the problem so that they can help other users with the same or a similar problem. Questions with a simple meaningful title can be easily found and the readers can quickly decide if it is relevant to them.

Answer (score 1):

Right click pick *Set Origin* and choose what you need.

The orange dot is the origin of the geometry, think of it as an anchor point, it defines how doe the mesh scale (always scales to the origin) and etc.